# swift - Open ViewController by clicking a button in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, swift

I have a ViewController named "test123" and I have UIWebView with a button:

```
<button onclick='myFunction()'>Open test123</button>
</body>

<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        presentViewController('test');

    }
    </script>
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38850026/opening-viewcontroller-when-click-on-button-in-uiwebview-swift) but I get `Use of undeclared type 'test123'`

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.formSubmitted) {
        let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("test123") as? test123

        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: VC!)
        self.navigationController?.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion:nil)


    }
    return true
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `as? test123` part that tries to downcast your object to a type `test123` that obviously does not exists.

Comment: ok it does build sucessfully but clicking the button does not open test123 viewcontroller

Comment: No, clicking doesn't do anything